# is LuisActionBinding.js removed from botbuilder-cognitiveservices.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I tried to use `LuisActionBinding.js` in my node.js chatbot and could not find `LuisActionBinding.js` like it exists in `BotBuilder-CognitiveServices\Node\samples\LuisActionBinding`

Comment: Did you see this [blogpost](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/03/luis-action-binding-bot/)? Your question is very vague and definitely needs more information / a code sample.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/lib/LuisActionBinding.js

Answer (score 0):

As Gary has indicated, the missing file can be found at this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/LuisActionBinding.js). Without your source code it's a little hard to actually help debug, but the most likely causes of your issue is you're using an older version of botbuilder-cognitiveservices.

I've setup a tiny project that just tries to import `LuisActionBinding` from BB-CS using [version 1.2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-cognitiveservices) and it works just fine:

```
const { LuisActionBinding } = require('botbuilder-cognitiveservices');
```